# Is there a way to select certain rows in a dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing a set of gene names and the expression of those genes in different cell types:

| Gene name | Cell type | Expression |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gene X | Cell A | 10 |
| Gene X | Cell B | 20 |
| Gene X | Cell C | 25 |
| Gene X | Cell D | 5 |
| Gene Y | Cell A | 7 |
| Gene Y | Cell B | 12 |
| Gene Y | Cell C | 16 |
| Gene Y | Cell D | 18 |
| Gene Z | Cell A | 15 |
| Gene Z | Cell B | 12 |
| Gene Z | Cell C | 16 |
| Gene Z | Cell D | 2 |

I only want to identify genes in which the expression in a certain cell type (e.g. Cell A) is greater than the expression of that gene in another certain cell type (e.g. Cell B). For instance, in this dataset I provided, this would be Gene Z. I have tried group_by and filter functions in R but I don't know how to compare specific expression values between different cell types within a gene when I group the data by gene. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to handle this issue or if there is another function in R to do something like this. Thank you!

Comment: Could you share your desired output?

Comment: Sure. "Gene Z" is my desired output in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in `tidyverse`, you can first transform the data to a "wide" format, and use `filter` to compare the expression of genes. Finally, `pull` the column out and you'll get a vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Cell.type", values_from = "Expression") %>% 
  filter(`Cell A` > `Cell B`) %>% 
  pull(Gene.name)

[1] "Gene Z"
```

Comment: Thank you very much foe help. Do I still need to do group_by ('Gene name') prior to running the code? when I try to do so I get the error message "no applicable method for 'pivot_wider' applied to an object of class "character". However, I want to make sure that the filter ('Cell A' > 'Cell B') is specifically applied within a single gene cluster.

Comment: @BioCode That is not necessary because `pivot_wider` will turn each gene into a single row

Comment: I get this error message when I try to use `pivot_wider`, 
"Warning message:
Values from "Expression" are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols."
Any ideas?

Comment: @BioCode From the error, it's likely you have duplicated cell name for the same gene.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `pivot_wider` your table so that every celltype gets its own column. **df** being your dataframe:

```
library(tidyr)
df_wide <-
    df %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = `Cell type`,
                    values_from = Expression
    )
```

Now you can filter:

```
df_wide %>%
    filter(`Cell A` > `Cell Z`)
```